# Добавление одиночных записей со связью ManyToMany

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, jpa

Имеются три таблицы **DIRECTORY**, **FILE**, **DIRECTORY_FILE**.

Таблица **DIRECTORY**

```
ID | NAME
 1 | directory_1
 2 | directory_2
```

Таблица **FILE**

```
ID | NAME
 1 | file_1
 2 | file_2
```

Таблица **DIRECTORY_FILE**

```
DIRECTORY_ID | FILE_ID
 1           | 1
 2           | 1
 2           | 2
```

Как средствами *JPA* сохранить одиночную запись (*DIRECTORY_ID* = 1, *FILE_ID* = 2) в таблицу *DIRECTORY_FILE*?

---

Решение *не устраивает* тем что для сохранения одной записи придется постоянно тянуть все данные о файлах принадлежащие данному каталогу:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILE")
class File {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    /**
     *  getters / setters
     */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DIRECTORY")
class File {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "DIRECTORY_FILE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DIRECTORY_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "FILE_ID") })
   List<File> files;

   /**
     *  getters / setters
     */
}
```

Comment: В случае, если вы моделируете классическую файловую систему, вам нужна связь типа OneToMany/ManyToOne.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток!

Вы можете создать ещё один Entity для связующей таблицы.

Comment: Что-то сомнительно...